# Eureka Registered with weird IP address and Requests not working with zuul

Tags: docker, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am developing a Rest Backend with microservices architecture using SpringBoot. I am using Eureka as discovery service and Zuul as API Gateway. Everything works fine when working in the localhost. But when I deploye the services on the cloud, zuul api gateway not behave as expected. All the services are still registered with the eureka. 
Request come to the api gateway not forward to the required sevice, instead it stuck on the api gateway and give

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ...
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:159)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 3b7b691a42eb: unknown error
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    ... 158 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 3b7b691a42eb: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    ...
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar:1.3.6]
```

Here is my zuul configurations

```
zuul:
    prefix: /api/v1
      routes:
        user-server:
          path: /user/**
          serviceId: USER-SERVER
        developer-server:
          path: /developer/**
          serviceId: DEVELOPER-SERVER

    spring:
      application:
        name: zuul-server

    server:
      port: 5000

    eureka:
      client:
        register-with-eureka: true
        fetch-registry: true
        service-url:
          defaultZone : http://{{eureka_hosted_ip}}:8070/eureka/   


hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 2000000
    ribbon:
        ConnectTimeout: 200000
        ReadTimeout: 200000
```

I have deployed services in docker containers.  What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the error. Error was when registering with the Eureka Server, my services doesn't register with correct ip address. Because it is run on a docker container it doesn't register ip correctly.
So when running docker I had to use `--network=host` part with docker run command. When I registered correctly with eureka everything works fine.